# Choose between Anaconda Python and other Python installation when Anaconda is set as the default Python - Windows 10

Tags: python, anaconda

The case is really simple. I am using Anaconda and have registered it as the default Python. As it seems, Anaconda has some issues with confluent_kafka library, therefore I need to install and use Python alone for a specific case.

I ran the installation (Python 3.10), added Python to path as well (so both Python are added to the path) but I don't have any clue on how to "point" and use the standalone Python explicitly in the desired case and Anaconda otherwise.

I have searched for the answer but came up with proposed solution on for Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I cannot comment on other answers, here is how you could install packages for different python versions

`c:/python3.10/python.exe -m pip install package_name`

Answer (score 1):

Use the full path of the executable, like `c:/python3.10/python script.py`

EDIT:
It can be located in another directory, check that with `where python` and adapt the first command

Comment: I also need to run pip install confluent_kafka specifically for 3.10 and not Anaconda. How can I achieve this