# Using the local pip version of a installed software (PsychoPy) to install a package

Tags: python, pip, psychopy

I am working with a software called PsychoPy, which runs on python and it brings it's own version of python and pip with it. I want to install a python package, so that it can be used with the version of python that is used by the software.
I've found the location of the python.exe as well as the various pip.exe, but I don't know how to use them to install a package.

Comment: If you have located python.exe file, you can use the same concept in this answer to install packages through python.exe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74374558/choose-between-anaconda-python-and-other-python-installation-when-anaconda-is-se/74374882#74374882

Answer (score 1):

You'll be glad to know that the next release of PsychoPy (2023.1) will have a dialog box built-in for this in the tools menu so that installing additional packages will be easier (and won't need admin permissions because the additional packages will be stored in user space).

In the meantime you'll need to use command line and, assuming the PsychoPy was installed to Program Files, you'll need to start command line with admin privileges (simply being logged in as an admin isn't enough). Then you just need to do

```
c:\<path-to-pip> install <name-of-package>
```